# inserting created by field in mysql table using java struts

Tags: mysql, struts2

I have 'CreatedBy' field in MySQL table.

I want to insert data in the table using java objects in struts action and service.

My Question is:

which way is better to insert 'CreatedBy' field in Mysql using struts.

1. Add 'CreatedBy' as a variable to the object (or)
2. directly get the username in service using session

Both are possible . But which is recommended as far as Struts is concerned.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. Maybe you can add some code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to insert createdBy field from session.

There is no concerns with such case for struts. It is your choice only which way to implement.